# AppSync/Amplify - how to define GraphQL subscriptions

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify to auto-generate queries, mutations and subscriptions. and I have this type:

```
type Message @model {  
  id: ID!
  author: User @connection(name: "UserMessages")
  content: String
}
```

How do I add authorID as a filter to subscriptions for new messages using Amplify generated schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add your own subscription fields that are parameterized however you like.

Try this

```
# Add the authorId explicitly and turn off the generated subscriptions.
type Message @model(subscriptions: null) {  
  id: ID!
  author: User @connection(name: "UserMessages")
  authorId: String
  content: String
}
type Subscription {
  onCreateMessage(authorId: String!): Message @aws_subscribe(mutations: "createMessage")
}
```

Subscribed clients only get messages with the authorId provided in the subscription query:

```
subscription SubscribeToNewMessages($id: String!) {
  onCreateMessage(authorId: $id) {
    id
    authorId
    content
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works well.  I guess there is no way subscribe by directly using the `id` in the `author` field, but instead, we'll have to add an extra param authorId?

Comment: I believe `mutations: "createMessage"` should be `mutations: ["createMessage"]`. I couldn't get it to work without the brackets.